# Any equivalent to Mockito's ArgumentCaptor in javascript test framework?

Tags: javascript, testing

I would like to capture the parameter passed to a stub method. And then I can perform assertion on the properties of that parameter. For Java, it is Mockito's [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html). Is there any equivalent thing in javascript test framework?

Comment: Which javascript test framework specifically are you talking about?

Comment: I am using mocha + chai + sinon + mockery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon  = require('sinon');

const obj = {
  divideByFive(a) {
    return a / 5;
  },
  testFunc(a, b) {
    return this.divideByFive(a + b) + 23;
  }
};

describe('obj.testFunc()', () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    // Restore to the original implementation
    obj.divideByFive.restore();
  });

  it('should call divideByFive() with the right arguments', () => {
    var spy = sinon.spy(obj, 'divideByFive');
    obj.testFunc(42, 1337);
    assert(spy.calledWith(1379));
  });

  it('should return the value returned by divideByFive(), increased by 23', () => {
    sinon.stub(obj, 'divideByFive').returns(1234);
    expect(obj.testFunc(42, 1337)).to.equal(1257);
  });

});
```

You can use `.calledWith()` (provided by Sinon) to check if a spy/stub was called with particular arguments. You should consult [the documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) for more options.

Here's a standalone Mocha test to check if a spy got called with an object that had particular properties set to particular values:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const sinon  = require('sinon');
const spy    = sinon.spy();

// Call the spy with an object argument.
spy({ foo : 'bar', xxx : 'yyy' });

// Check the properties.
it('should have called spy with foo:bar', function() {
  assert( spy.calledWithMatch({ foo : 'bar' }) );
});

it('should have called spy with xxx:yyy', function() {
  assert( spy.calledWithMatch({ xxx : 'yyy' }) );
});

it('should have called spy with xxx:zzz (WILL FAIL)', function() {
  assert( spy.calledWithMatch({ xxx : 'zzz' }) );
});
```

Comment: Because the parameter I passed is an object rather than single value, and I want to check several properties inside that object. Is it possible to do that with calledWith?

Comment: `.calledWith()` only matches an argument exactly, but `.calledWithMatch()` will allow you to match objects partially (if, for instance, you want to make sure that only a particular property is set to a particular value, regardless of any other properties that the object might have).

Comment: Thanks I tried and it works. Can you provide an example with calledWithMatch? So I can mark that as answer.